# Suppose that the spot price...

Tags: valuation-theory

Suppose the spot price of gold is \$300 per ounce and the risk-free
interest rate for one year is 5%. What is a reasonable value for the one-year forward price of gold?

**The answer is \$315, right?**

Suppose the one-year forward price of gold is \$340. Argue as follows: borrow 300 dollars for a year and buy one ounce of gold. Then short a forward contract to sell the gold in one year time. Show this will lead to a risk-free proﬁt (arbitrage) and the the one-year forward  price  of  gold  must  be  $315.

**This comes down to \$340 - $315 = \$25 , right?**

**I suppose that the \$315 here cones again from the \$300*105% ? right?**

Then assume the one-year forward price of gold is \$300. Argue  as  follows:  sell the  gold,  then  invest  the  proceeds  and  long  a  one-year  forward  on  gold.  Show  again  that  this  will  lead  to  a  risk-free  proﬁt  (arbitrage) and  the  one-year  forward  price  of  gold  must  be  \$315.

**I'm  confused  cause  of  this  part.  So  if  anybody  could  help?**

thanks  in  advance

I don't know what goes wrong with the notation but when I design the question I don't have a problem until I upload the text. Therefor I wanted to upload an image. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgjGh.png)

Comment: The notation went funny because dollar signs are used here to delimit "math mode" based on LaTeX. In order to have a dollar sign show up, put a backslash in front of it. (I've edited this fix into your post - it should show up soon)

Comment: Waw, that really is an eye-opener to me! Thanks for helping me out! As you might have figured. I'm new to this website.

Answer (score 1):

Your first part is correct.

For the second part, if the forward price of gold is the same as the spot price then you can sell the gold today for $\$300$ and put the money into an account earning $5\%$ interest. At the same time you go long on a one year forward contract. This means you agree to pay $\$300$ an ounce a year from now.

In a year you have $\$315$ from the return on your investment so you can buy your gold back and earn a free $\$15$. That's what arbitrage is. Since everyone would do this it would drive the forward price up to $\$315$.